# What version of cqlsh is compatible with cassandra 3.10?

Tags: cassandra, centos7

Installed cassandraa 3.10.1 but get error(cannot make connection) when trying to run cqlsh. What version of cqlsh is compatible?
sudo yum install cassandra-3.10-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: What is the output of `nodetool status` ?

Comment: All versions of Cassandra ship with a version of cqlsh that should work with it.

Comment: Also, make sure the process is running and check if is there any errors during cassandra startup

Answer (score 0):

`cqlsh` version `3.4.0` will support with `cassandra 3.10`

```
$ cqlsh <host> -u <username> -p <password> --cqlversion="3.4.0"
```